# How to access a registered singleton service from Android-specific code, such as a foreground service?

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

If I would have a registered Service in .net maui like an HTTPClient service as such:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Startup : IStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IAppHostBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            appBuilder
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddSingleton<IHTTPClient, HTTPClient>();
                });
        }
    }
}

public interface IHTTPClient
{
    Task<string> GetAsync(string url);
    Task<string> PostAsync(string url, HttpContent content);
}

public class HTTPClient : IHTTPClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public HTTPClient()
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAsync(string url)
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    public async Task<string> PostAsync(string url, HttpContent content)
    {
        var response = await _client.PostAsync(url, content);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

How could I access this Service from within android specific code like a ForeGroundService, since the injection is not possible in an android service and the MauiApp.Current is not accessible like so:

```
MauiApp.Current.Services.GetService<IHTTPClient>();
```

The example android service I want to access the HTTPClient service from:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Microsoft.Maui;

namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    [Service]
    public class MyForegroundService : Service
    {
        public const int SERVICE_RUNNING_N

        OTIFICATION_ID = 10000;

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            var notification = new Notification.Builder(this, "my_channel_id")
                .SetContentTitle("My Foreground Service")
                .SetContentText("My Foreground Service is running...")
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notification_icon_background)
                .SetOngoing(true)
                .Build();

            StartForeground(SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For this, you can check this link: [How to reuse Xamarin Dependency Service in .NET MAUI?](https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/issues/187).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that

```
var httpClient = MauiApplication.Current.Services.GetService<IHTTPClient>();
```

should be what you're looking for.
And it should be accessible even within Android specific code, sine the Android's MainApplication derives from MauiApplication itself.

EDIT: Though upon another glance, your code doesn't seem to follow the MAUI structure exactly as I know it... Is your app somehow manually converted from Xamarin.Forms to MAUI perhaps?